# Airflow: Only allow one instance of task

Tags: airflow

[image: DAG Tree view]

Is there a way specify that a task can only run once concurrently? So in the tree above where DAG concurrency is 4, Airflow will start task 4 instead of a second instance of task 2?

This DAG is a little special because there is no order between the tasks. These tasks are independent but related in purpose and therefore kept in one DAG so as to new create an excessive number of single task DAGs.

`max_active_runs` is 2 and `dag_concurrency` is 4. I would like it start all 4 tasks and only start a task in next if same task in previous run is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules) for trigger rules:

`depends_on_past` (boolean) when set to True, keeps a task from getting triggered if the previous schedule for the task hasn’t succeeded.

So the future DAGs will wait for the previous ones to finish successfully before executing.

Comment: This won't work if you have to rerun failed tasks that are interleaved by successful instances.

Answer (score 4):

I may have mis-understood your question, but I believe you are wanting to have all the tasks in a single dagrun finish before the tasks begin in the next dagrun. So a DAG will only execute once the previous execution is complete.

If that is the case, you can make use of the `max_active_runs` parameter of the dag to limit how many running concurrent instances of a DAG there are allowed to be.

More information here (refer to the last dotpoint): https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html#why-isn-t-my-task-getting-scheduled

> max_active_runs defines how many running concurrent instances of a DAG there are allowed to be.

Comment: No, I don't mean instances of the DAG but instances of each task in the DAG.

Comment: If that's the case, you could look into using different `priority_weight` to have tasks within a dag executed in a particular order. You should also take a look at the various trigger rules you can apply to a dag. You can find more info on them [here](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules). You may be able to use the `depends_on_past` rule, but keep in mind that trigger rule relies on the  task succeeding (not just finishing).

Answer (score 3):

[Airflow operator documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/index.html) describes argument `task_concurrency`. Just set it to one.

Answer (score -2):

On airflow.cfg under [core]. You will find

> dag_concurrency = 16
>   //The number of task instances allowed to run concurrently by the scheduler

you're free to change this to what you desire.

Comment: My question is not related to instances of the DAG but instances of each task in the DAG.

Comment: I'm sorry, your number of Dags is also 4 so I misunderstand. May I ask how do you define the trigger rules? because normally task will trigger when upstream task succeeded. You can see the official [link](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules)